# Hosting ActiveX control inside Flipview

Tags: c#, wpf, flipview

I have tried hard to host an ActiveX control in Flipview but have been unable to achieve desired result. I'm using Windows 7 and Flipview control, as found on codeproject (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741026/WPF-FlipView). I'm actually embedding a flash movie into my project, and on swiping the new movie should be loaded.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MTC.SIMVA.IC.Controls.WPFFlashControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:fla="clr-namespace:AxShockwaveFlashObjects;assembly=AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" >
    <DockPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="flashMovie">
            <fla:AxShockwaveFlash x:Name="flashMovie2" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I have also made custom control to wrap AxShockwaveFlash control. My view is as follows:

```
<dl:FlipView x:Name="flipView" ItemsSource="{Binding Flows}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="flipView_SelectionChanged">
        <dl:FlipView.DataContext>
            <vm:SwipeWinViewModel />
        </dl:FlipView.DataContext>
        <dl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel x:Name="mainPanel" LastChildFill="True">

                    <DockPanel x:Name="topPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#E4E4E4" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="80">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" VerticalAlignment="Center" Block.TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" Margin="200,0,200,0" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <DockPanel x:Name="animPanel" Background="LightBlue" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DockPanel}}}">
                        <uc:WPFFlashControl x:Name="flashControl" MovieSource="{Binding Source}"/>

                    </DockPanel>

                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </dl:FlipView>
```

A window is displayed but nothing is shown. However, when I use custom control without FlipView it works fine, so I think there is problem with FlipView Control. Is it possible to use such custom control in datatemplate of FlipView  control?